# Code with kpfonts takes years to compile. Any faster way?

Tags: packages, compiling, texmaker, kpfonts

I would like to start by asking if the package "kpfonts" makes any improvements to the way the font looks. I wrote a small code and then I added the package kpfonts and I have the feeling that the letters are more smooth. (It's not clear from the definition from [here](ftp://ftp.ccu.edu.tw/pub/tex/fonts/kpfonts/doc/kpfonts.pdf): *Kp-Fonts provides a full set of fonts for LaTeX typesetting, including roman, sans-serif et fixed-width fonts, as well as a set of mathematics symbol fonts with, regular and bold, all the common symbols and all those of the ams and more*)

Anyways, coming back to the original issue... I am writing my thesis and I have over 200 pages and to make it PDF, it takes like 20 seconds. If I add the package "kpfonts", the CPU starts to heat, the fan goes crazy and nothing happens... I am not sure what the problem is. Anyone has any suggestion on how to make this process faster? Also, is there any replacement for kpfonts that does the same improvement to the font?

P.S. The editor is TeXMaker, if this makes any difference.

Edit:

I have made a MWE with the package that I suspect it causes the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\cee{CO2 <=>[Gas] CO} &
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

After compiling using pdflatex, I get this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\getanddefine@fonts ...p@font \let \textfont@name\font@name \xdef \font@nam... \end{align}
```

So, apparently the mhchem package is incompatible with kpfonts... Or?

Comment: kpfonts doesn't "make improvements to the font" it's just a different font, so whether it is better or worse is just subjective. It shouldn't have a noticeable effect on runtime, presumably something is not correctly installed and causing tex to search your disk for something, but hard to guess what from the description.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the answer. It's also hard to me to provide a MWE, because it's a 200 pages. But, as I said... It works perfectly fine if I don't use that font, but once I load it, my computer gets crazy, and I don't get it why...

Comment: Done that. I have loaded even the "lipsum" package and added lines like crazy. It works perfectly fine. I also loaded the document style "Thesis.cls". I first thought it was something wrong with the style (which I got from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) if it is of any help. 

But when I do that in my thesis... dead end...

Comment: so it's a problem in your thesis not with kpfonts so you would need to start from a copy of your thesis and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem to make the smallest example that reproduces it. Not much else we can suggest...

Comment: I guess it is a problem with my thesis. I will try to disable package by package and see where is the conflict, if any. The text itself has only figures and text, so that shouldn't affect the font change, right?

Comment: Start rather by commenting out text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Comment out, say, the last half, and try to compile; if the problem persists, comment out half of the remaining half, and so on. Worry about the packages later.

Comment: @Paul who knows perhaps there is a bug in a package that means some little used symbol `\foohookharpoonarrow` is defined to be itself and puts tex into an infinite loop if used in a document, and you happen to use it on page 199 of your thesis. really it could be anything.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I am trying now to remove parts of the text and then I will try disabling packages. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: how far does it get, the terminal and log should show [1][2]...[10]... as each page is made, which should give an indication of where in your thesis the problem is.

Comment: All right. So I ran the pdflatex command in the terminal. When I add the package, I get this: 
[9 <c:/Users/P/Image/Image.jpg>] 
! Underfined control squence.
\getanddefine@fonts ...p@font \let \texfont@name 
\fond@name \xdef \font@nam...
l.121 \end{align}

Comment: you get an _error_? you didn't mention that:-) so it should be easy to narrow down to a document that just has that align from page 9 or 10.

Comment: please show errors in a code section (`{}` button in the site editor), it's impossible to read without the original line breaks as the line break is the indication of which command is undefined, but if it is `\fond@name` that looks a lot like a typo for `\font@name`

Comment: Okay. So the most common error is "! Undefined control sequence.\getanddefine@fonts ...p@font \let \textfont@name\font@name \xdef \font@nam... \end{align}" 

Do you have any idea what this is? Can it be that "kpfonts" is not compatible with equations? I can see that the error appears where I have equations...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48306/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-paul).

Comment: the MWE  runs without error in texlive 2016